# Saving memoization to disk

Tags: memoization, save

I like using memoization (i.e. the construct `myFunction[x_]:=myFunction[x]=...`) when I have a heavy function that I need to re-evaluate on the same arguments. However, I find it frustrating that each time I quit the kernel(s), all the advantage goes lost.

Is there a way of saving the results? I can think of a very cumbersome way of doing it, such as this block upon defining our function

```
memo = If[FileExistsQ[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "memo.mx"}]], Import["memo.mx"], {}];
myFunction[x_] := Module[{value = ...},
AppendTo[memo, "myFunction[" <> ToString[x] <> "]=" <> ToString[value]]; 
Export["memo.mx", Union@memo];
myFunction[x] = value]
Evaluate[ToExpression/@memo];
```

Is this okay, or is there a better (or even designated) way of doing this?

Comment: And `DumpSave`?

Comment: I guess that does it! (I'm checking)

Comment: Yes! Thank you :D

Comment: @unlikely Can you post an answer?

Comment: [Here's a solution using `Once`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193305/26598) to construct persistent memoization.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not much different from your approach and maybe not the best/safest approach, but `DumpSave` helps a bit because at least you don't have to works with strings:

```
cacheFile = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "fibonacciCache" <> ".mx"}];
If[FileExistsQ[cacheFile],
 Get[cacheFile],
 fibonacci[1] = 1;
 fibonacci[2] = 1;
 fibonacci[n_Integer] := Module[{},
   fibonacci[n] = fibonacci[n - 1] + fibonacci[n - 2];
   DumpSave[cacheFile, fibonacci];
   fibonacci[n]
   ]
 ]
```

For example

> In[3]:= fibonacci[500] // Timing
>
> Out[3]= {0.562500, \
>   1394232245616978801397243828704072839500702565876973072641089629483255\
>   71622863290691557658876222521294125}

Now `Quit[]`-ing and reevaluating the previous cell:

> In[3]:= fibonacci[500] // Timing
>
> Out[3]= {0., \
>   1394232245616978801397243828704072839500702565876973072641089629483255\
>   71622863290691557658876222521294125}

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach with [`LocalSymbol`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalSymbol.html):

````
PersistentMemoize[key_, expr_] := Module[{name, value},
  name = "PersistentMemoize/" <> ToString[key // Hold // InputForm];
  value = LocalSymbol[name];
  If[Head[value] === LocalSymbol,
    value = LocalSymbol[name] = expr;
  ];
  value
];
SetAttributes[PersistentMemoize, HoldAll];

ClearPersistentMemoization[] := DeleteObject[LocalObjects["LocalSymbols/PersistentMemoize"]];

(* example *)

fib[n_] := fib[n] = PersistentMemoize[fib[n],
  Print["computing fib[" <> ToString[n] <> "]..."];
  fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]
];
fib[1] = 1;
fib[2] = 2;
```
````

Comment: Actually, after writing this answer, a further search leads me to [an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193305/74569) that looks nicer.