# Save part of memoized function

Tags: series-expansion, save, memoization

I have a function whose performing a series of expansions of a complicated function, which can take a lot of time. To avoid bottlenecks, I use memoization so I need to evaluate it only once.

For completness let's say it is simply

```
f[a_, trunc_] := f[a, trunc] = Series[Sin[a*x], {x, 0, trunc}] // Normal;
```

In my script I will need several expansions for different `a` at a given `trunc` (defined at the beginning of the script and not modified until the end). As evaluating `f` can take more than a minute and I need order 50 values of `a`, I usually place a

```
Save["savedExpansion.m", f];
```

at the end of the script so that next time I can directly load it with `Get` and same myself some time.

Now, I want to create a script that basically doing only the initialisation of f for both the values of `a` and `trunc` I will ever need so that I have everything that takes time to compute once and for all. I wrote the following snippet of code

```
listA = Table[a, {a, 1, 10}];
listTrunc = Table[trunc, {trunc, 1, 10}];

Do[
    ParallelDo[Print["Going over ",a];f[a, trunc];, {a, listA}];
    Save["savedExpansionTrunc" <> ToString[trunc] <> ".m", f];
, {trunc, listTrunc}];
```

The thing is that each created file contains the values for `f` of all the previous values `trunc`, which I want to avoid to save memory. I there a way of saving only the values of `f[a,trunc]` for a given `trunc`? Moreover, is it possible to clear the values from memory with `Clear` without clearing the definition of the function at the same time?

By the way, is there a best practice for these kinds of things, e.g. using `Save` rather than `Dump`, or using parallelisation?

Comment: My ABBYLingvo does not include "memoized". Is it a new English word? What does it mean?

Comment: @user64494 [Memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html), [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a common term in programming for functions that remember output for specific input. It's a relatively new word (1968).

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193305/26598 ?

Comment: @Roman my question is more about how to save `f` in a file only for a subset of value (i.e. for a given `trunc` rather than everything) than how memoization or Once work. The file that I create will be sent to different machines, so I need to get a file in the end.

Comment: Is it the series expansion that takes a lot of time?  Or the numerical evaluation for a given `a`.  If the expansion takes a lot of time you can curry `f` by doing something like `f[trunc_] := 
 f[trunc] = 
  Function[a, Evaluate[Normal@Series[Sin[a x], {x, 0, trunc}]]]` and then calling `f[0][1.23]` or `f[2][4.56]`.  When you save f you would just save the functions, not the numerical evaluations.

Comment: (Also notice that in the above case `x` is still an unbound variable).

Comment: I still think `Once` would be a good solution. `Once` storage is in regular files at any location of the filesystem that you like, even on network shares, so you can easily transfer these files between different machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you set a value, you can later unset it. For example:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[n_] := f[n] = n^2;
Do[f[n], {n, 3}]; DownValues[f]
Do[f[n] =., {n, 2}]; DownValues[f]
```

first sets the values for `f[1], f[2], f[3]` and then unsets all but the last. The `DownValues[f]` allows you to check these values. You can now save the function `f` and its remaining set value.

Answer (score 1):

If the expansion takes a lot of time and the subsequent numerical evaluation is easy, you might just want to store the series expansions.  One way to do this is by currying `f`, as in

```
f[trunc_] := f[trunc] = Function[a, Evaluate[Normal@Series[Sin[a x], {x, 0, trunc}]]]
```

and then you can save `f` and it saves the expansions.  You then evaluate `f[3][4.56]` (`trunc=3`, `a=4.56`, for example).  Note that the result is a function of `a` and has an unbound `x` (in your example).

If you just want to remember values for a specific `trunc`, you can do something like

```
worker[trunc_, a_] := Normal@Series[Sin[a x], {x, 0, trunc}]

wrapper[trunc_, a_] := worker[trunc, a]
wrapper[1, a_] := wrapper[1,a] = worker[trunc, a]
```

which will save values for `wrapper[1,a]` but not for other values of `trunc`.  You can add additional `trunc`s (or `a`s or pairs of `trunc` and `a`) to be remembered by adding additional specializations of `wrapper`.