# Is there a way to store a solution function obtained by numerically solving a pde?

Tags: datastore

Let us say we have a partial differential equation to be solved numerically, we input all the initial conditions and boundary conditions and ask mathematica to solve for us a numerical solution $u(t,x,z)$. Let us also suppose it takes around 3 hours for the program to solve it numerically, then when we want to do something about this $u(t,x,z)$, say plot it, the kernal crashed.

And we are forced to execute the command again which would take another 3 hours, so I was thinking if there is a way to store and restore the previously solved function so we can use it right away after quitting the kernal?

Comment: MMA has a few ways of saving output in a file.  Most notably of which are [`Put`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html), [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html), [`Save`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html), and [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html).

Comment: but how to apply it to a function generated after NDSolve? Could you give an example

Comment: You can use `Once` with a memoization idiom: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193305/74569

Comment: Usually I use `DumpSave` for this task

Comment: The answer is absolutely yes. Now that relevant functions have been mentioned, I then point out that file of format ".mx" can be used.

Comment: You cannot win back the solved data from yesterdays solving. Though you could have let it run overnight and have had the result this morning